# How to generate Entity Relationship diagram for a set of tables stored in Sqlite DB and produced by a specific Airflow dag ID run

Tags: python, sqlite, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, erd

New to Airflow. I have some tables in airflow DB.
I want to produce an entity relationship diagram to relate these tables.

I have tried the method

from eralchemy import render_er

render_er("sqlite:////directory/to/airflow.db", 'testing.png')

But it returned an error
File ".....sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 1223, in **getattr**
return self._index[key]
KeyError: '_data'

Although connecting to the database would give me airflow metadata, I would rather a solution to produce an ER diagram from my specific table created by my dag id.